# How does Cardano differentiate itself in the DeFi space?

Tags: defi

How does Cardano differentiate itself in the DeFi space? What's the fastest way to start experimenting with applications?

Answer (score 0):

Cardano differentiates itself as smart contracts are written in a more functional way than Ethereum Solidity contracts, so you can test Cardano contracts on your local machine, confident that they will run the same on the production network. Also, Cardano has things like Native assets, which simplifies handling of tokens.

Answer (score -2):

At this moment, they are no DeFi applications deployed on Cardano as we're waiting for smart contracts.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/504)

Comment: Right, hard to answer as Cardano does not differentiate itself in the DeFi space as it is not in DeFi space.

Comment: Are there any perceived or hypothetical advantages that are known at the moment based on the properties we know to be true about the behavior of eutxos and plutus?